# Create or not a protocol when using delegate

Tags: objective-c, delegates

I have the following code:

VCA.h

```
-(void)updateArrayMethod;
```

VCA.m

```
-(void)updateArrayMethod
{
    // Implementation to update array in VCA.
{

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"SegueDetalhes"]) {
        VCB *viewB = ((VCB *)segue.destinationViewController);
        viewB.delegate = self;
    }
}
```

VCB.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic)id delegate;
```

VCB.m

```
#import "VCA.h"
```

Implementation:

```
- (IBAction)buttonClick:(id)sender
{
    [self.delegate updateArrayMethod];
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Now, this works fine for me, my question is conceptual. Is there an actual difference in using protocols for this case? Or is it just a rule to keep the code clean?

For example, I could achieve the same thing doing in VCB.h

```
@protocol MyProtocol <NSObject>
-(void)updateArrayMethod
@end

@property (nonatomic,assign)id<delegate>delegate;
```

and then adopt and implement the protocol in VCA.m and delete the method declaration in VCA.h.

Is there a difference besides code organization?

Comment: Actually, it is still a protocol. It's called an "informal protocol". You don't declare it anywhere but there are some methods that the `delegate` has to define otherwise your app will crash. Informal protocols were used a lot in the previous releases of both iOS & MacOS but they were fragile and they have been replaced with formal protocols step by step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing without the protocol is very fragile and it doesn't scale. Your `VCB` has to import `VCA`. This means that your `VCB` now has knowledge of `VCA`. What if later you want `VCB` to handle a delegate that isn't a `VCA`? Now you need to make sure that `VCX` implements the same method and adds it to the `VCX.h` file. Then you need to update `VCB` to import the `VCX.h` file.

That's starts to get ugly fast.

It's much better to define a protocol specific to `VCB` and put it in the `VCB.h` file. Then your `delegate` property should be `id<MyProtocol>`.

Now you can create any number of classes (not just view controllers) that conform to the protocol. Any of these can be set as the delegate. And `VCB` never knows about the specific classes. `VCB` doesn't need to be updated. It just knows that some class conforms to the protocol and provides the needed method.

Nice, neat, and clean.